# Terraform Azure fails to create Database

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database

Im using terraform 2.33.0 (I tested 2.90.0 too ) to create a sql server and then create a database

Today Ive started getting the following error:

> Error waiting on create/update future for SQL Database "x" (Resource
> Group "y", Server "z"): Code="45157" Message="Server 'z' is busy with
> another operation. Please try your operation later.

I can create the sql database in the portal fine after this failure.

Has anybody seen this issue or anything like it?

The SQL Server is created like this:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "tenant_sql" {
  name                         = "fakename"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.tenant_rg.name
  location                     = var.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = var.sql_server_admin_login
  administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_server_admin_password.result

   tags = {
        Application = "blah"
      Tenant = var.tenant
      CustomerId = var.customer_id
      Environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

The db is created like this

```
resource "azurerm_sql_database" "tenant_sqldb" {
  name                             = "x"
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.tenant_rg.name
  location                         =  var.location
  server_name                      = "fakename"
  create_mode                      = "Default"
  edition                          = var.database_is_premium == true ? "Premium" : "Standard"
  requested_service_objective_name = var.database_is_premium == true ? "P4" : "S1"
  max_size_bytes = 268435456000
   tags = {
      Application = "bah"
      Tenant      = var.tenant
      CustomerId  = var.customer_id
      Environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

This all executes as one script!

Its worth noting that azurem_sql_database is deprecated so perhaps the RM API behaviour has changed and azurem_sql_database isnt accounting for this.

Comment: Please add formatting to the question to make it easily readable.

Comment: Was the SQL server `z` fully created before the database creation failed?

Comment: I reckon it wasnt. What Im suprised at is that the Azure plugin for Terraform should manage this since it was the same terraform script building both.

Comment: I upgraded to latest (at the time)  which is 2.93.1 of the AzureRM (which requires terraform 0.12.31 minimum) and this didnt solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by moving away from the deprecated azurerm_sql_server to azurerm_mssql_server and azurerm_sql_database to azurerm_mssql_database